# Make a selection in one jcombobox enable a different jcombobox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have 7 jcomboboxes that all start with the same default selection. How do I make then next one enabled when something other than the default if selected in the preceding jcombobox?

```
        if ( ! (custData1.equals("Please Select a Customer from the dropdown menu")) ){
        custData2.setEnabled(true);
        if ( ! (custData2.equals("Please Select a Customer from the dropdown menu")) ){
            custData3.setEnabled(true);
            if ( ! (custData3.equals("Please Select a Customer from the dropdown menu")) ){
            custData4.setEnabled(true);
            if ( ! (custData4.equals("Please Select a Customer from the dropdown menu")) ){
            custData5.setEnabled(true);
            if ( ! (custData5.equals("Please Select a Customer from the dropdown menu")) ){
            custData6.setEnabled(true);
            if ( ! (custData6.equals("Please Select a Customer from the dropdown menu")) ){
            custData7.setEnabled(true);
            }
           }
          }
         }
        }
    }
```

This doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom `JComboBox` by extends `JComboBox`.  Make that class take in a reference to the preceding combobox. Have it and itself as an `ActionListener` to the preceding box and whenever an item is selected it should enable/disable itself.