# Make a state change in one jcombobox enable a different jcombobox

Tags: java, jcombobox

I have 7 jcomboboxes, say:
customerInfo1
customerInfo2
customerInfo3
customerInfo4
customerInfo5
customerInfo6
customerInfo7

All but the first one are set to setEnabled(false) and have setSelectedItem("Please Select a Customer from the dropdown menu"). I am having the hardest time figuring out how I would go about listening for a state change on customerInfo1 which would then make customerInfo2 setEnabled(true). And, once customerInfo2 is enabled have a state change event trigger the same thing for customerInfo3, and so on. Basically I don't want a given customerInfo jcombobox to be enabled until something other than what was initially set is selected in the preceding one. Your clear and specific help is much appreciated.

Comment: You have posted the same question withe even the same title : "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376546/make-a-selection-in-one-jcombobox-enable-a-different-jcombobox".

Comment: Thought that possibly rewording things would help me get a clearer answer. I started learning Java a little under 2 months ago. I am currently struggling with this final aspect of my project.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a focus listener on the combo boxes such that if a combo has lost focus then you can check about the condition and take your action accordingly!!!

eg

```
  if we have a combo box then we would add a focus listener on it and check the condition whether the check box is checked or not then add the required combobox.

     JComboBox jb1;
     jb1.addFocusListener(this);
```

this is to be done in main and the following code in other method in the same class

```
     public void focusLost(FocusEvent fe) 
     {
          //your code for enabling or disabling the combo box
     }
```

this should do the required thing

Regards
ChArAnJiT

Answer (score -1):

You need to call a JavaScript method on change event of the first combo box.

Say if you change the state of the first combo box, this JavaScript method will be called and it will change the state of other combo boxes as u wish.

Same thing have to be done for all the other combo boxes.

Comment: What you say I understand, but its going about this that is what I am struggling with.

Comment: Wow, Javascript has absolutely nothing to do with the problem, but thanks for playing.